# Java: do/while loop repeating even though condition has been met

Tags: java, do-while

I'm trying a simple do while loop that is suppose to run if the input is less than 1, and greater than 1000. It should ask for the user to input a correct number, on loop otherwise. What it seems to be doing now is repeating the loop one additional time, asking for the correct input, and then display the ending message. Unsure why it's repeating it, if the condition is met

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Please enter students lastname");

int input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Please enter students ID"));

do {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Please enter a student ID within the correct parameters");
    input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please enter students ID"));
} while (input < 1 && input > 1000);

// Output dialog with user input
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "StudentID: " + input
        + "\nStudent Last: " + name);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a number that is less than 1 and greater than 1000?

Comment: you understand that a do-while executes *before* checking the condition, right? So it will run until input==1002

Comment: `(input < 1 && input > 1000)` can never be true!

Comment: The condition should be `(input < 1 || input > 1000)`, to accept numbers between 1 and 1000, right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would change it with a `while`:

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
    "Please enter students ID"));
while(input < 1 || input > 1000) {
    // Your stuff
}
```

---

**The explanation**

What I think was wrong is that, in the first place, there's no way any number can be (at the same time) less than 1 and more than 1000, so obviously, the valid input should be *outside* the specified range (that is, from `-Infinity` to `0` ***OR*** from `1001` to `Infinity`).

Secondly, what was mentioned in another answer: The `do...while` loop always runs at least once, and it repeats as long as the `while` condition is true. Since the input is being read *before* entering the loop, the 'confirmation`always takes place... What's the need to request a correction on a possibly correct`input` value?

What I think was wrong is a misunderstanding on the sense of the validation rule:

> *I'm trying a simple do while loop that is suppose to run if the input is less than 1, **and** greater than 1000*

What does the **and** word means? I think it means that the input must be *outside* the given range.

Comment: not sure why this got marked as the answer as it wasn't the first answer *and* doesn't explain what's actually wrong.

Comment: @Colleen I've edited my answer explaining what I think was wrong. By the way, an accepted answer "doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked" (from the *About* page: http://stackoverflow.com/about )

Answer (score 5):

You're presenting the dialog at least twice -- once before the loop, once within the loop.

The do-while does not test the condition until after the loop has executed at least once.

You could either:

- Eliminate the first call to show the input dialog.
- Or change your do-while loop to a while loop.

In addition, see @GrailsGuy's comments on the loop test. Your current test will always fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you while CONDITION is not correct as I read comments in print statement I believe you need

```
 while (input > 1 && input < 1000);
```

Because ID must not negative number.

Remember this condition is true if ID value is between `2 to 999`.

**As you commented**: *Just to clarify, if the user inputs a number outside of the range (1-1000),i.e. 2005, I want the loop to cycle, asking the user to input a number within the range,until that condition is met*

do like, read comments to understand what My code is:

```
input = -1;
while(input < 1 || input > 1000){ 
//    ^              ^ OR greater then 1000
// either small then 1   
}
```

**notice:** I have punted OR instead of AND because either one condition fail you loop should be continue.

Comment: Just to clarify, if the user inputs a number outside of the range (1-1000),i.e. 2005,  I want the loop to cycle, asking the user to input a number within the range,until that condition is met.

Comment: @user1901231 my answer was just an guess answer based on info provided + what I could understand. Let me check If I am wrong